# translate-cloak not working with partial loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to integrate translate partial loading into my app, but there is a flicker on initial load of the translation file (when changing states). I'm using `translate-cloak` as suggested but I still get the same effect.

**Note** The flicker only happens when when changing the partial, not the language.

Here is my setup

**Config**

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider){
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: 'dist/locales/{lang}/{part}.json'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
}])
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($translate, $translatePartialLoader){
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('app');
  $translate.refresh()
});
```

**Template**

```
<div translate="HEADLINE"></div>
```

**Layout**

```
<html ng-app="app" >
  <head>
    <title>SportProphecy</title>
    <script src="/dist/js/vendors.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ui-view ng-cloak translate-cloak>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? I have read through all the documentation out there regarding `translate-cloak`.

PS: I tried creating a fiddle but for some reason the `json` files aren't being requested.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "Flash of untranslated content" from the angular translate docs. You might want to check it out [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

Basically, you need to define atleast one language to be loaded synchronously. So go ahead and add translations for your preferred language ('en' in your case) in the app.config

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider){
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: 'dist/locales/{lang}/{part}.json'
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');

  $translateProvider.translations('en-US', {
    'HEADLINE': 'My Fancy App!'
  });
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

**svikasg** is completly right. Though as a workarround you can do the following inside your controller:

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('my-part'); //this should be already in your controller

var vm = this;
function updateCloak () {
    vm.cloak = $translate.instant('some_translation_id') === 'some_translation_id';
}   
$rootScope.$on('$translateLoadingEnd', function () {
   $timeout(updateCloak);
});
updateCloak();
```

And then in your page container where you're using the translations add an `ng-if="ctrl.cloak"`. You can also use ng-class if you prefer.

Of course you need to inject `$rootScope, $translate, $timeout` in your controller also.

This code will set a cloak scope property to true as long as an expected translation is not available, allowing you to hide the parts using the translations in the same file than the one you're checking.

**Note**: if you're not using controllerAs syntax replace all the `vm` references with scope and remove the `ctrl.` from the `ng-if`.